# How To refer to import range formulas saved in a cell

Tags: google-sheets

i use Query function to import data from other google sheets files like this :

```
=QUERY({
        IMPORTRANGE("First Sheet URL","first sheet range"); 
        IMPORTRANGE("Second Sheet URL","Second Sheet Range")
       },
           "SELECT * ",0)
```

what i want now is to save these IMPORTRANGE formulas on a cell like this :

```
A1 = IMPORTRANGE("First Sheet URL","first sheet range")
A2 = IMPORTRANGE("Second Sheet URL","Second Sheet Range")
```

And then refer to those cells, so the query formula will become like this :

```
=QUERY({
        A1; 
        A2
       },
           "SELECT * ",0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to try

```
=QUERY({
        IMPORTRANGE(A1,B1); 
        IMPORTRANGE(A2,B2)
       },
           "SELECT * ",0)
```

with URLs in A1 and A2 and ranges in B1 and B2

Comment: is it possible to use array formula like this 

=QUERY({
        ARRAYFORMULA(
                                     IMPORTRANGE(A1:A2,B1:B2)
      ) },
           "SELECT * ",0)

Comment: No it's not possible as is! If you want to do so, we will need a script, that's another question.